# Tomcat, Grunt build

Tags: java, angularjs, node.js, tomcat, gruntjs

I am using grunt for my angular js app, and tomcat for my server side.

Whenever needed, in dev env, I run Grunt build, takes dist folder and put it in tomcat webapp folder.

However, I have a weird issue. URLs within the app work only if I click on them from an HTML page.

e.g. if I type `http://localhost:8080/upload` - I will get `404 page not found error`, however if from index page - `http://localhost:8080` , I click on a link in page that leads to upload it works fine.

What could be the problem?

If I run the app on node.js, the links work perfectly! just on Tomcat it doesn't work as expected.

**EDITED**

I define the urls like this in angular js

```
angular.module('angularjsApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('upload', {
        url: '/upload',
        templateUrl: 'app/upload/upload.html',
        controller: 'UploadCtrl'
      });
  });
```

Comment: have you configure properly in `web.xml` may be that could me reason cause of which it unable to find paths

Comment: it's a standard web.xml that I have been using in all my apps what else needs to be configured?

Comment: is `/upload` is this url is defined in backend??

Comment: no! only on client side. where do I define it?

Comment: it means that I have to define everything twice? in client and backend? and what if I need to send parameters from client and the client handles it :( ?

Comment: then try `http://localhost:8080/#/upload` then it will serve from angular code

Comment: that works! do you want to write it as an answer? but what if a search engine refers to my page? it will refer to /upload or /#upload?

Comment: Added as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have angular setup its using history push state to navigate, changing the browser's URL without actually causing the browser to re-fetch its content from the back end.

So using push state the in the browser angular can navigate just fine, but when a request is actually sent to the server it responds 404 as you have nothing there to serve your HTML.

There are two solutions to this:

1. Switch to use #! urls so that from the server you're always getting the same URL (see other answers).
2. Update your server to serve the same static HTML for all paths (this answer).

You need the servlet that's sending back your initial HTML content to do so for all routes - so mapped to `/*` rather than just `/` so any path it's given always returns the same HTML.

So your web.xml has a servlet that looks like this that's returning:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>StaticHtmlServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.StaticHtmlServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StaticHtmlServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> <!-- so this is what's added -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I don't understad. can u pls explain more?

Comment: Explained a bit more.

Comment: An example of the servlet: https://github.com/thaggie/drop-angular/blob/master/src/main/java/com/demo/AngularServlet.java

Comment: An example of the template: https://github.com/thaggie/drop-angular/blob/master/src/main/resources/angular.html

Comment: I know that it's old, but I need to use it now - what is the config URL parameter?

Comment: You mean https://github.com/thaggie/drop-angular/blob/master/src/main/java/com/demo/AngularServlet.java#L27 ? that points to where the client static files are.

Comment: Thanks. so angular.html should be as it is?

Answer (score 1):

In order to server by AngularJs then add `/#/` after the domain and make sure **html5** mode default enabled is `false`(`$locationProvider.html5mode`).Below the example for your app to serve content from client site(angular-js)

```
http://localhost:8080/#/upload
```

Comment: how would the search engine will act? if it leads to /upload I will get 404. if I write rewrite rule it will be infinite..

Answer (score 0):

Are the links actual standard HTML links? If Tomcat doesn't answer for `http://localhost:8080/upload`, then maybe it's not a `GET` request.